# Moto mock s3 seems to run but can't find files

Tags: python, amazon-s3, pytest, boto3, moto

I'm trying to mock an s3 instance with `Moto`, which does seem to work, however for some reason it seems to search the real s3 for files instead of the mocked s3.
My working hierarchy looks something like this:

```
root
--tests
----mock s3
------__init__.py
------conftest.py
------test mock s3.py
```

In `conftest` I'm mocking s3 like this:

```
fixture
def mock s3():
  mock = mock_s3()
  mock.start()

  client = boto3.client('s3')
  add buckets and keys to the client

  yield client

  mock.stop()
```

And `test mock s3.py` looks like this:

```
usefixtures('mock s3')
def test_something():
  path = Path('s3://bucket/key')
  files = all the files from the path
  assert some stuff
```

And when I run `pytest tests/mock s3/test mock s3.py` it seems to work fine. However if I don't call the file directly when I run `pytest` (for example `pytest tests/mock s3`) for some reason it doesn't seem to use my mocked s3, `files` gets back the real files from s3.
The mock fixture still gets applied (I know because I added prints which got printed) but for some reason it can't find the files in the mock.

EDIT -- added path and files to `test_something`

Comment: Have you tried using moto as a decorator over test method as opposed to a fixture? Just for comparison

Comment: @OleksiiDonoha Thanks for the suggestion, but the same thing happens. When I test the file specifically it works, when i test the directory it doesn't